# jQuery DataTables POST Server Side Json error

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, post, datatables

my Table is not correctly loaded via ajax.

Here is my js:

```
$('#initAjaxDataTable').DataTable( {
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": $('#initAjaxDataTable').data('url'),
        "type": "POST"
    },
    language: {
        url: SITEURL + 'libraries/datatables/datatables.german.json'
    },
    "columnDefs": [
        { "data": "adressnummer", "defaultContent": "<i>Keine</i>", "targets": 0 },
        { "data": "name", "defaultContent": "<i>Keine</i>", "targets": 1 },
        { "data": "email", "defaultContent": "<i>Keine</i>", "targets": 2 },
        { "data": "street", "defaultContent": "<i>Keine</i>", "targets": 3 },
        { "data": "zip", "defaultContent": "<i>Keine</i>", "targets": 4 },
        { "data": "city", "defaultContent": "<i>Keine</i>", "targets": 5 }
    ]
} );
```

And here is my JSON returned from server:

```
{"draw":1,"data":"[{"DT_RowId".........:}]","recordsTotal":24301,"recordsFiltered":50,"error":null}
```

Data short example:

```
[
{
    "DT_RowId": "row_1",
    "adressnummer": "9002",
    "name": "test data",
    "email": "",
    "street": "test 26",
    "zip": "16307 ",
    "city": "test",
    "DT_RowData": {
        "pkey": "1"
    }
},
{
    "DT_RowId": "row_2",
    "adressnummer": "9003",
    "name": "test data",
    "email": "",
    "street": "test 24",
    "zip": "16306 ",
    "city": "test",
    "DT_RowData": {
        "pkey": "2"
    }
},
{
    "DT_RowId": "row_3",
    "adressnummer": "9006",
    "name": "testtest data",
    "email": "",
    "street": "test17",
    "zip": "16306 ",
    "city": "test",
    "DT_RowData": {
        "pkey": "3"
    }
},
......
```

My Table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered " id="initAjaxDataTable" data-page-length="50" data-url="/importlist">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>AdressNummer</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>E-Mail</th>
            <th>Strasse</th>
            <th>PLZ</th>
            <th>Ort</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

</table>
```

My Table shows 24301 times the default content in every column.

I am using jquery Datatables in Version 1.10.9 and jQuery in Version
 2.1.4

What i am doing wrong?

EDIT: Json Lint says my json is valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my problem with the following code:

```
"ajax": {
        "url": $('#initAjaxDataTable').data('url'),
        "type": "POST",
        "dataSrc": function (json) {
            json.data = jQuery.parseJSON(json.data);
            return json.data;
        }
    },
```

i have added the dataSrc attribute to ajax and parsed my json

Comment: Or possibly just `"dataSrc": ""`